# Assigning a value to the first row of a multindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with multilevel indexes that looks somewhat like this:

```
                 value  diffs 
 ticker   date              
   A      22     0.55    NaN
          32    -2.50  -3.05
          76    -0.79  -0.56
   B      59    -1.01  -0.22
          72    -1.24  -0.23
   C      22    -1.29  -0.05
          63     1.65   2.94
```

How do I change the first row of each level so that I can get:

```
                  value  diffs 
 ticker   date              
   A      22     0.55    0
          32    -2.50  -3.05
          76    -0.79  -0.56
   B      59    -1.01    0
          72    -1.24  -0.23
   C      22    -1.29    0
          63     1.65   2.94
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `groupby`, e.g.

`df['diffs'] = df.values.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: (x-x.shift(1)).fillna(0))`

Answer (score 0):

there is probably a better way but this works, first we can see that the multi-index is composed of various levels and labels, the labels show us when the level changes:

```
In [77]:
df.index

Out[77]:
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C'], [22, 32, 59, 63, 72, 76]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 5, 2, 4, 0, 3]],
           names=['ticker', 'date'])
```

So we can construct a Series from the first labels array and detect when the level changes using `shift` and use this to index into the df:

```
In [78]:    
labels = pd.Series(df.index.labels[0])
labels[labels != labels.shift()]

Out[78]:
0    0
3    1
5    2
dtype: int8
```

the index from above we can pass to `iloc` to select the first row of each top level group:

```
In [82]:
df['diffs'].iloc[labels[labels != labels.shift()].index]

Out[82]:
ticker  date
A       22       NaN
B       59     -0.22
C       22     -0.05
Name: diffs, dtype: float64
```

We can now assign the value:

```
In [83]:
df['diffs'].iloc[labels[labels != labels.shift()].index] = 0
df
Out[83]:
             value  diffs
ticker date              
A      22     0.55   0.00
       32    -2.50  -3.05
       76    -0.79  -0.56
B      59    -1.01   0.00
       72    -1.24  -0.23
C      22    -1.29   0.00
       63     1.65   2.94
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach to solve the problem is to transpose the dataframe and apply a loop.

```
T = df.T
for name in T.columns.levels[0]:
    T.loc[T.index[-1], name][0]=0
```

For example, with your data, you will get the following:
(I did not add the names and I simply replys the `NaN` by `-1`)

```
data=np.array([[ 0.55, -1], [-2.50,  -3.05], [-0.79,  -0.56],
[-1.01,  -0.22], [-1.24,  -0.23], [-1.29,  -0.05], [ 1.65,   2.94]])

index=[np.array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']),
np.array(['22', '32', '76', '59', '72', '22', '63'])]

df=pd.DataFrame(data,index=index)
df
         0     1
A 22  0.55 -1.00
  32 -2.50 -3.05
  76 -0.79 -0.56
B 59 -1.01 -0.22
  72 -1.24 -0.23
C 22 -1.29 -0.05
  63  1.65  2.94

T = df.T
for name in T.columns.levels[0]:
    T.loc[T.index[-1], name][0]=0

df
         0     1
A 22  0.55  0.00
  32 -2.50 -3.05
  76 -0.79 -0.56
B 59 -1.01  0.00
  72 -1.24 -0.23
C 22 -1.29  0.00
  63  1.65  2.94
```